# Internet Explorer Compatibility Issue - Microsoft Expression web

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility, microsoft-expression-web

I'm working on creating a website for my intern project, and I have created the site through Microsoft Expression Web. Originally, when I opened the html file on Chrome & Internet Explorer, it looked and worked fine. 
However, I had to copy/paste the whole file into a different file to share with my mentors, and after I moved it, the website only looks & works like the original one only on Google Chrome. It looks messed up when I open the html file through IE. Is there any thing I can do to fix this ? Any tags I can put in , fix, or force to open in chrome maybe? I just need any solution. Thank you !

Comment: I have researched many ways to fix this problem but haven't came with a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, like your HTML Source. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Like @AlexandreT mentions above no one is going to be able to help you unless you provide some code for us to look at.